# onTouch not working on listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, ontouchlistener

Am creating an application where I have a fragment, the xml for the fragment is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cvCalendar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Calendar"
        android:divider="#cecece"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:background="#e4c966" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have a Linearlayout on top, which is used to display a calendar, and the events of the calendar are shown in below list.
I want to have a feature that on swipe up, calendar gets hidden and on swipe down, it shows back the calendar. 
The java code is given below

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        cala=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Calendar);
        rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

            onTouchEvent(event);
          }
        return true;
           }
        });
          return rootView;
         }
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
    {
       switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                x1 = touchevent.getX();
                y1 = touchevent.getY();
                break;
              }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                x2 = touchevent.getX();
                y2 = touchevent.getY();

                if (y1 < y2)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UP to Down Swap Performed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if ((cala.getVisibility())== View.GONE){
                       cala.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }
                  }

                if (y1 > y2)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Down to UP Swap Performed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   if ((cala.getVisibility())== View.VISIBLE){
                       cala.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
                   }
                break;
               }
          }
       return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
--onCreate()

```
lvListObject.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```